# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect /oauth2/authorize endpoint form - redirect_uri error

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I have an application (.NET 5.0 ASP Net Core) application that I am trying to deploy to an AWS Amazon Linux 2 server.  It appears that all aspects of deployment are fine except for authorization with AWS Congnito and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.  Everything works fine in dev/local and the problems only exhibit themselves when in prod deployment.

The issue exhibits itself as an "An error was encountered with the requested page." at `https://auth.<mydomain>.com/error?error=redirect_mismatch&client_id=<myclientid>` in the Hosted UI when trying to login. I have confirmed and reconfirmed that the Callback URL(s) are set correctly: `https://sub.domain.com/signin-oidc, https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc`.

My app is running on http://localhost:5000 behind an apache reverse proxy. I suspect that the non-HTTPS portion of the path between Apache and Kestrel is the issue.

What I have noticed is that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect is lacking https in the redirect_uri value that it creates as part of the /oauth2/authorize endpoint it calls.

This is what I see in Dev (no issues):
[image]

This is what I see when deployed, note that the redirect_uri is http:
[image]

In the App client settings, I can't set the signin-oidc endpoint to use the HTTP.

My ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.ResponseType = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ResponseType"];
                options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:MetadataAddress"];
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"];
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = "cognito:groups"
                };
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTicketReceived = e =>
                    {
                        e.ReturnUri = string.Format("/Home/CheckProfile?url={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(e.ReturnUri));
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
        }
```

So, why is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect using HTTP when it generates the redirect_uri value of the /oauth2/authorize endpoint.  Is that somethign that I need to adjust somewhere? And, does that appear to be the core issue that results in my overall `https://auth.<mydomain>.com/error?error=redirect_mismatch&client_id=<myclientid>` issue?

Comment: Please share relevant code where auth is configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better answer.  While the "Kestrel exposed to the world" answer worked, I ended up figuring out how to  make the reverse proxy work with Cognito.

In the reverse proxy I ended up setting "'https' env=HTTPS" as shown here:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" 'https' env=HTTPS
</VirtualHost>
```

I also rearanged my Prod Configure(...) as follows:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   app.UseForwardedHeaders();
}
else
{
   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
   app.UseForwardedHeaders();
   app.Use((ctx, next) =>
   {
      ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("sub.domain.com");
      ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
      return next();
   });
   app.UseHsts();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The core issue here was the reverse proxy; Kestrel running behind Apache.  While I had used this setup (with certbot) regularly over the past few years, I had not previously used it with a OIDC auth scheme.  The issue was the https termination at apache and the http transmission between Apache and Kestrel. An OIDC auth scheme (in my case supported by AWS Cognito) needs end-to-end https.

The "lacking https in the redirect_uri value that it creates as part of the /oauth2/authorize endpoint" was just the first of many issues I uncovered.  I came up with a solution for that issue:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
   ...
   options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
   {
      ...
      OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
      {
         n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Replace("http://", "https://");
         await Task.FromResult(0);
      }
   };
});
```

But this only solved the narrow issue of changing the redirect_uri proto; other cookie SameSite=None/Secure/http issues then appeared.

At this point, I have had success directly exposing Kestrel on 80 and 443.  I realize that it's debatable whether this is a prudent idea, but it's working for me at the moment and today (Summer 2021 on .NET 5.0) it seems like Kestrel is maturing to the point where it is not one of those "only do this in development!" tools.

I found both of these articles very helpful:

https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-run-aspnet-core-as-a-service-on-linux

https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/05/07/certificates-and-limits-for-asp-net-core-kestrel-web-server/